# Using a lambda in place of an index-able template parameter

Tags: c++11, templates, lambda

I have a method that takes an index-able object as a template parameter, something like:

```
template <typename OBJ>
int foo(int n, OBJ o)
{
  int x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    x += o[i];
  }
  return x;
}
```

Is there a way I can pass a lambda function in for the `o` parameter? In other words, having the lambda be call-able via the `[]` operator rather than the `()` operator?

Comment: No it's not possible. You need to pass an object which implements `operator[]`, and lambda objects don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class F>
struct square_bracket_invoke_t {
  F f;
  template<class T>
  auto operator[](T&& t)const
  -> typename std::result_of< F const&(T&&) >::type
  { return f(std::forward<T>(t)); }
};
template<class F>
square_bracket_invoke_t< typename std::decay<F>::type >
make_square_bracket_invoke( F&& f ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc72709d091c6d4b).

Code is C++11 and has basically zero overhead.

```
int main() {
  std::cout << foo( 6, make_square_bracket_invoke([](int x){ return x; } ) ) << "\n";
}
```

result is 0+1+2+3+4+5 aka 15.

Is this a good idea?  Maybe.  But why stop there?

For max amusement:

```
const auto idx_is = make_square_bracket_invoke([](auto&&f){return make_square_bracket_invoke(decltype(f)(f));});
int main() {
  std::cout << foo( 6, idx_is[[](int x){ return x; }] ) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Very nice. A question for my edification. What does `std::decay<F>::type` do for a lambda?

Comment: @RSahu If `F` is `X const&` it is `X`.  If it is `X&` it is `X`.  If it is `X` it is `X`.  Except if `F` is a function or reference to function or array or reference to array type.  Lambdas are none of those.  `decay` makes a type suitable for storage as a value; for example, passing it into a function.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There are still many corners of C++11 I am yet to reach.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by:

1. Creating a class template, a functor, that has the `operator[]` defined.
2. Implementing the `operator[]` in terms of the `operator()` of a `std::function`.
3. Storing the lambda in a wrapped `std::function` as a member variable of the class template.

Here's a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename OBJ>
int foo(int n, OBJ o)
{
  int x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    x += o[i];
  }
  return x;
}

template <typename> struct Functor;

template <typename R> struct Functor<R(int)>
{
   using ftype = std::function<R(int)>;
   Functor(ftype f) : f_(f) {}

   R operator[](int i) const { return f_(i); }

   ftype f_;
};

int main()
{
   Functor<int(int)> f = {[](int i) -> int {return i*i;}};
   std::cout << foo(10, f) << std::endl;
}
```

and its output

```
285
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/8XtU3s)

#### PS

`Functor` is not the appropriate name here. It does not overload the function call operator. I suspect there is a more appropriate name.

Comment: I dislike passing in the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it helps, here's a way to forward a wrapper class's `operator[]` to your lambda's `operator()`.

```
template<class F>
struct SubscriptWrapper_t {
  F f_;
  template<class T> auto operator[](T const& t_) const -> decltype(f_(t_)) { 
    return f_(t_); 
  }
};
template<class F> 
SubscriptWrapper_t<typename std::decay<F>::type> SubscriptWrapper(F&& f_) {
  return{std::forward<F>(f_)}; 
}
```

I use wrappers like this a lot.  They're convenient, and they don't seem to have any computational overhead, at least when compiled by GCC.  You can make one for `at` or even make one for `find`.

EDIT: Updated for C++11 (and updated to be able to return a reference)

Comment: not `decltype(auto)` in C++14?  In 11, which the OP asked for, this won't work.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I should have read the question tags better.  It's updated now, albeit made redundant.

Answer (score 0):

A sketch of a wrapper type that would do this.

```
template<typename UnaryFunction>
class index_wrapper
{
public:
    index_wrapper(UnaryFunction func) : func(std::move(func)) {}

    template<typename T>
    std::invoke_result_t<UnaryFunction, T> operator[](T&& t)
    { return func(std::forward<T>(t)); }

private:
    UnaryFunction func;
};
```

With usage

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename OBJ>
int foo(int n, OBJ o)
{
  int x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    x += o[i];
  }
  return x;
}

int main()
{
  index_wrapper f([](int i) -> int { return i*i; });
  std::cout << foo(10, f) << std::endl;
}
```

You might want to restrict it to a single parameter type, so that you can provide member type aliases similar to `std::vector::reference` et.al.

Comment: This is C++17 -- OP asked for 11